# runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)' , expected ']' found 'NAME' when running a xpath query in excel vba

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xpath

I'm trying to write a macro to process data from an xml file in VBA. All my queries work just fine except one that uses multiple condition.

```xml
    <Meetings>
        <Meeting>
           <Object>Budget</Object>
           <startHour>15</startHour>
           <endHour>19</endHour>
        </Meeting>
    </Meetings>
```

Here is my XPATH query that raises the issue

```vb
Sub test (xmlDoc) 
    Dim hour As Single
    Dim node
    hour = 17 
    Set Node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Meetings/Meeting[startHour<" & hour & " and endHour>" & hour & "]/Object")
    Range("A1").Value = Node.Text 
End Sub
```

It raises runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)' , expected ']' found 'NAME'. 
I tried to do queries with each individual conditions and they worked. I think the problem has something to do with the "and" syntax but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Your query appears to work: [`//Meetings/Meeting[startHour<17 and endHour>17]/Object`](http://xpather.com/1Gud9R9Q)

Comment: NB you will also need to `Set Node = ...` otherwise another error will raise.

Comment: Yes sorry the Set was a typo mistake but it was in my macro code. I correct it :) But it still does not work into excel vba ...

Comment: Your XPath expression is fine. Can you please check (e.g. by printing) what the result of `"//Meetings/Meeting[startHour<" & hour & " and endHour>" & hour & "]/Object"` is exactly? Also, it is possible that this is a limitation of the VBA implementation of XPath. Is the XML document you are showing an accurate example for your _actual_ document, did you leave out any namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple approach.

```
//Meetings/Meeting[startHour[. <17]][endHour[.>12]]/Object
```

[image]

**What's wrong with your xpath:**

You can use the operator < or > on the node directly, rather you have to get the text and then use the operators.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for the clarification. I updated the answer. Hope you will take back the downvote now :-)

Comment: Looks better :) Still not sure what's wrong with OP's attempt, when I try it that way, it works for me on xpather.com

Comment: This answer does not identify the problem the OP has (the XPath expression should work fine) and the proposed XPath expression is needlessly complicated.

Comment: That almost worked for me. This query works well when hour is an integer. When its decimal i needed to update my code a bit : my excel uses the European decimal format (with a coma), whereas the microsoft XPath interpreter uses the american format. Simple solution : cast hour to a string and use replace.
Here is my final code : 

  ` s= Replace(cStr(hour),",",".") `
  ` Set Node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(//Meetings/Meeting[startHour[. <" & s & "]][endHour[.>" & s "]]/Object") ` `code`